# Error detected while installing Kali Linux 2020.1b on virtualbox 6.1

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, system-installation

It shows that there is "invalid settings detected "  I need an answer to solve that error to get the ok button on the virtual box to start[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please refrain from adding images, copy/type the necessary info so that other users can yank them for searching

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `Secure Virtual Machine` in your host. To do this, first restart your PC. Head to the **BIOS** settings by pressing the necessary keys(it's F2/Del in most systems, yours may differ)

Go to **Advanced>>CPU Configuration>> Secure Virtual Machine**

Set this option to **Enable** . Save your changes and restart. Now the problem should be resolved.

**P.S:** the BIOS menu in your system may be a little different, look for the  right entries by cross-checking